# SQL, VB.Net | What query can I use grab this value?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

[image]

In the above I want it to give me the value of "ID" of the "Username" associated with it.

Here is the command I tried

```
Dim Query2 = String.Format("SELECT ID FROM account WHERE character = " & UsernameTextBox.Text & " ")
            Command = New MySqlCommand(Query2, mydbcon)
            Dim idtest = reader.Read.ToString
            MsgBox(idtest)
```

however it is returning "false" what am I doing wrong?

Here is the entire code that I am working on:

```
Try
        mydbcon.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = '{0}' AND password = '{1}'", Me.UsernameTextBox.Text.Trim(), Me.PasswordTextBox.Text.Trim())
        Dim Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, mydbcon)
        reader = Command.ExecuteReader

        Dim count As Integer
        count = 0
        While reader.Read
            count = count + 1
        End While

        If count = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Username and password are correct")
            Query = String.Format("SELECT username AS ID FROM account WHERE character = " & UsernameTextBox.Text & " ")
            Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, mydbcon)

            My.Settings.LoginID = reader.Read
            MsgBox(My.Settings.LoginID)
        ElseIf count > 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Username and password are duplicate")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Username and password are wrong")
        End If
        mydbcon.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mydbcon.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Comment: Dont concat SQL.  Use Parameters.  Dont store passwords as plaintext.  According to the image, if that is the Account table, there is no col named character.

Comment: ...and `it is returning "false"`  what is "it" exactly? that code snippet is not a function, so it can be *`it`*.  If you were to execute that second query, you'll get a different error.

Answer (score 0):

Use ID as alias (so `select username AS anyNameYouWantToAssignToIt`):

```
Dim Query2 = String.Format("SELECT username AS ID FROM account WHERE character = " & UsernameTextBox.Text & " ")
```

Comment: it is still returning false. What is it trying to equal it to?